# jQuery function to fill up a form won't work

Tags: jquery, arrays, forms

I've written a function to fill up a form tag. The script creates the options but it won't fill up the option-tags with my array entries. I hope you can help me.

Here is my Code

```
window.onload = function() {
    var VideoListe = $("VideoListe");
    for (i=0;i<Videos.length;i++) {
        var Entry = $("select").append('<option>');
       //Entry.text= Videos[i][1];
       $('<option>').append(Videos[i][0]);

        VideoListe.add(Entry ,null);
    }
}
```

edit: here ist the HTML Code for that issue:

```
 <div class="wr_chapters">
    <form>
    <select id="VideoListe">
    </select>
    <button onclick="nextClip()">Zum nächsten Video</button>
  </form>

  </div>
```

Comment: First of all `var VideoListe = $("VideoListe");` you must have forgotten `#` or `.` sign in front of the selector

Comment: @Muuta could you also paste some html. It's not clear whether VideoListe is a css class or id.

Comment: Sry i've forgotten the html Codeblock. VideoListe is a ID

Comment: @Muuta I've solved your last removed question here is the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SCPLf/1/)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
window.onload = function () {

    // Get the VideoListe element first with proper ID or class
    var VideoListe = $("#VideoListe");

    // Cache the select element here
    var Entry = $("select");
    for (i = 0; i < Videos.length; i++) {

        // Create a dynamic option with array data
        var $option = $('<option/>', {
            text: Videos[i][0],
            value: Videos[i][0]
        });

        // Append the option to the select list
        Entry.append($option);
    }

    VideoListe.add(Entry, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var VideoListe = $("#VideoListe"); //or class not sure abt that
if(VideoListe .length > 0) {
var chunks = '<select>';
   for (i=0;i<Videos.length;i++)
   {
    chunks +='<option>'+Videos[i][0]+'</option>';

   }
chunks +='</select>';
  //now chunks will be a select element
}

});
```

Comment: You included the error mentioned in the comment by the question: $("VideoListe");

Comment: OOPs sorry abt that @TJ.

Comment: Also please could you explain what the difference between your code and the OPs code is, so he/she understands what was wrong. As is this is just a code snippet.